# How to choose type of output from a water level switch?

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits

I need to buy a level switch for a quench tower water drainage system. I intend to use its output directly to open a solenoid valve to drain the tank when the switch detects water and close it afterward when the water recedes. I have identified make and model of a level switch I think is good. But the manufacturer provides multiple types of electrical outputs. It would be great if someone could advise on which of the following type is best for a simple level switch - solenoid valve circuit.

1. Relay
2. NAMUR
3. Transistor
4. 2-wire

P.S: I am a newbie regarding electrical stuff. I'll consult a friend who will help me to design the circuit, but I just need to place the order for the level switch.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering.SE .  Could you add a link to the family of the sensors that you like?  Could you tell us what you're going to connect the sensor to?

Comment: Can you share the make and model of the Level Switch? Can you share the specification of the Solenoid Valve?

Comment: What are the current and voltage requirements to "directly to open a solenoid valve"? If these matched those of the "relay" option you might be able to not use a relay itself, but chances are pretty high that you will just have to use a relay or transistor in the middle and go with the appropriate output option.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a latching solenoid valve like the following?

[image]

[1/2" Magnetically Latching Solenoid Valve DC 6 V](https://ussolid.com/1-2-magnetically-latching-solenoid-valve-dc-6-v.html)

Use a h-bridge driver to switch on and off the valve. Below is one that I have used most recently.

[DRV8833 Dual Motor Driver Carrier](https://www.pololu.com/product/2130)
\
[image]

HTH

Comment: The only reason to add the additional complexity would be to conserve energy but this does not seem to be an issue for the OP.